# Threading Class - 'int' not iterable | Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I'm current encountering an issue where I'm using threads to perform tasks in the background upon a POST request, but I'm having an issue with using an integer as a parameter; or any data type as a parameter for that matter.


What is supposed to happen is that it's supposed to perform everything inside of the POST request check, then perform something else after that has been completed.

Imports:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template, redirect, request
from flask.cli import with_appcontext, click
import sqlalchemy
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_required, current_user
```

Thread Class:

```
@click.command(name='run')
@click.pass_context
class Compute(Thread):
    def __init__(self, secs):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.secs = secs

    def run(self):
        print('Thread Opened')
        sleep(self.secs)
        db.session.query(Users).filter(Users.username == current_user.username).first().requests += 1
        db.session.commit()
        print('Thread Closed')
```

Flask Route:

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        time = '5'

        thread = Compute(int(time))
        thread.start()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else:   
        return render_template('index.html')
```

The error I am receiving when the thread tries to start is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request     
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 272, in decorated_view    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/myuser/Desktop/Projects/Python/app.py", line 104, in layer4
    thread = Compute(int(time))
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\click\core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\click\core.py", line 767, in main
    args = list(args)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I am not very experienced with threading, I've only dabbled with it in other projects so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error; any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback and the imports?

Comment: @egrubbs Yes, I've just updated the post.
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I think there is some issue with passing the params to Compute. Thread takes args in tuple format and not in int. 

There can be more simple approaches for using threading.

Comment: @Simplecode What would one of those simpler approaches be?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `@click.command` and `@click.pass_context` decorators.

```
@click.command(name='run')
@click.pass_context
class Compute(Thread):
```

Those decorators are wrapping the class in a function that takes its own parameters. It is intended for running a function from the command line and parsing arguments. This is why the traceback shows `args = list(args)` as the line causing the error.

https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/master/src/click/core.py#L916-L917

```
        :param args: the arguments that should be used for parsing.  If not
                     provided, ``sys.argv[1:]`` is used.
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response.
I've tried this already, but I need to pass application context because I'm using SQLAlchemy inside of the threading class.

Comment: You can use @click.pass_context on a function, and that function can call Compute(secs).start()

Comment: I've tried using this, but I get `RuntimeError: There is no active click context.`
From some research, I need to use `click.group()`, but then I get my original error.

Comment: If you don't give us a traceback, we just have to imagine how the entire codebase of flask, sqlalchemy, and click interact. I really think you shouldn't be trying to use click for this. I'm assuming you are using Flask-SQlAlchemy. Although this article recommends not using it, you may just be able to use it as a guide to use db.create_session() in the thread as opposed to sessionmaker() that the article calls directly.
https://towardsdatascience.com/use-flask-and-sqlalchemy-not-flask-sqlalchemy-5a64fafe22a4